# Do WP8 Kid's Corner games and apps uses the same accounts?

Tags: 8.0, kids-corner

Summary of Kid's Corner:

> ...They can open Kid’s Corner on their own, but your Start screen, apps, and info are protected by a password you set.
>
> [Kid's Corner](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/features?ocid=sem_features&&cmpid=sem_OFAw1s9s_pcrid_1615027774_kwd_windows%20phone%208%20kids%20corner_pmt_b#kids)

I want to know if a game I use and my kid uses will share the same account in Xbox Live and settings in different apps.

I mean, Kid's Corner have a different account for games **AND** apps?

I'm afraid she can lost my "healthy" or my "coins" in some games I play "for real".

Answer (score 3):

Only one account per phone, and its the one used for kids corner. 
I understand what you want to do but haven't found it to be possible at this time.

I've got a number of Windows Phone feedback route listed at http://dfwiki.devfish.net/technology.Microsoft-feedback-routes.ashx .  You ought to push that up as a suggestion.

Some good kid's corner FAQs at http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/basics/kids-corner-faq and http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/basics/set-up-kids-corner .